# Why PHP Laravel returns `500 Server Error` for Rule->unique()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using the following validation in the controller:

```
$request->validate([
'name' => [
       'required',
        'max:50',
        Rule::unique('center_classes')
       ]
]);
```

I also tried the following:

```
$request->validate([
'name' => [
       'required',
        'max:50',
        Rule::unique('center_classes', 'The class name exist.')
       ]
]);
```

I have the following line in the **validation.php**:

```
'unique' => 'The :attribute has already been taken.',
```

The rest of errors are working properly but `Rule->unique()` is the only one which causes `Error Server` instead of passing message.

> [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 287ms]

Answer (score 0):

You need to send validation error manually into your code like this

```
    //use first
    use Validator;    

    $response = array('response' => '', 'success'=>false);

    $rules = array('name' => 'unique:center_classes,name');       

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $response['response'] = $validator->messages();
        }else{

    //process the request
       }
    return response()->json($response);
```

Comment: you want to center_classes as a unique in database right ?

Comment: can you say center_classes table name

Comment: okay, center_classes in which field contain unique class name

Comment: i write systax on ans plz try theme

Comment: It returns the same thing. Didn't fix.

Comment: write in comment you validation line

Comment: you need send validation error manually into json in api response, i write code for you above ans

Comment: probleam is other becuase this code i use many time , add your wall code of api in question

Comment: Okay , good now track you code write dd('hi') in validation fail section and then fire api